# How do I access multiple buttons from an NSObject?

Tags: swift, uibutton, nsobject

I'm very new to Swift and programming in general so bear with me:

I created an NSObject to access multiple texts and buttons.

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeScreen: NSObject {

var messageText: String?
var imageName: String?
var buttonName: UIButton?

static func sampleScreens() -> [WelcomeScreen] {

    let splitButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Split", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "IBMPlexSans", size: 25)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 249/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #f1f9fe */
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 33
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.tag = 0
        return button
    }()

    let playButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "IBMPlexSans", size: 25)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 249/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #f1f9fe */
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 33
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        button.tag = 1

        return button
    }()

    let splitScreen = WelcomeScreen()
    splitScreen.messageText = "It's simple, start splitting your bill"
    splitScreen.imageName = "SplitButton"
    splitScreen.buttonName = splitButton



    let otherScreen = WelcomeScreen()
    otherScreen.messageText = "Choose a random party member to pay for the whole meal"
    otherScreen.imageName = "PlayButton"
    otherScreen.buttonName = playButton

    return [splitScreen, otherScreen]
}
```

}

And here is where I access the text and the images but I can't access the buttons.

```
class ButtonCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var button: WelcomeScreen? {
    didSet {
        if let text = button?.messageText {
            descriptionText.text = text
        }
        if let imageName = button?.imageName{
            splitButtonView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
        splitButton = button?.buttonName
    }
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpView()

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let splitButtonView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "SplitButton"))

    //enables autolayout for our imageView
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    return imageView
}()


var splitButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Split", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "IBMPlexSans", size: 25)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 249/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #f1f9fe */
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 33
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    return button

}()
let playButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "IBMPlexSans", size: 25)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241/255, green: 249/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #f1f9fe */
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 33
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    return button
}()

private let descriptionText: UILabel = {

    let textLabel = UILabel()

    textLabel.text = "It's simple, start splitting your app"
    textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "IBMPlexSans-Light", size: 20)
    textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textLabel.textAlignment = .center
    textLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
    textLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
    textLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    textLabel.numberOfLines = 2


    return textLabel
}()
func setUpView(){
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


    addSubview(descriptionText)
    addSubview(splitButtonView)
    addSubview(splitButton)



    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-30-[v0]-30-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": descriptionText]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-30-[v0]-30-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": splitButton]))
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-50-[v1(==70)][v0(==70)]-40-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": splitButton, "v1": descriptionText]))

}  
}
```

My program has multiple cells and the different text and images appear on the different cells. I'm trying to figure out how to have my buttons show up on the different cells as well. Here are screen shots:

[First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy1oX.png)
[Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhGZj.png)

I hope I made that clear. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. the majority of this code is from various swift tutorials on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better and easier to create custom collection view cells rather than creating a custom object. In all my time developing for ios with swift, I've only had to instantiate from NSObject when dealing with objective c.

Comment: I believe I did create custom cells. The bold title is my header cell and everything below that are swipable cells. The last snippet is part of a class for my bottom cells.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I over looked that line of your code. Which object are you trying to access and where?

Comment: I am trying to access the button I created in my WelcomeScreen: NSObject class. I'm able to populate my descriptionText variables in both of my cells but I'm not able to populate both of my buttons.

Comment: I access my descriptionText and splitViewImage in the "var button: WelcomeScreen?" in the ButtonCell class. The NSObject is in a separate Swift file than my ButtonCell class.

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you are trying to do. That's an interesting issue. Are you getting any kind of error? And if you are what line?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, it just displays the button I created in the "class ButtonCell: UICollectionViewCell". So it must not even be reading the other button in the NSObject class.

Comment: Okay, I've never implemented UI this way before. It would make sense to me to remove the two buttons you created in you CollectionViewCell because they are the same as the two you made in you WelcomeScreen class. Kinda removes the point of having those button created.